# Jquery ui Dialog closes immediately without any user action

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

A first dialog works well. Here is the method I'm using :

HTML `<div>` :

```
<div id="newarticle-form" title="Cr&eacute;ation nouvel article">
    <form id="newarticleform" method="post" action="articles/ajout">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="validite" class="label-class">Date de validit&eacute;</label>
        <input type="text" name="validite" id="validite" size="10" maxlength="10" class="text input-class" />
        <label for="libelle" class="label-class">Libell&eacute;</label>
        <input type="text" name="libelle" id="libelle" size="50" maxlength="100" class="text input-class" />
        <label for="email" class="label-class">Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="" size="50" maxlength="250" class="text input-class" />
        <label for="pu" class="label-class">Prix unitaire</label>
        <input type="text" name="pu" id="pu" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" class="text input-class" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
        <p class="validateTips"></p>
</div>
```

Javascript jquery ui dialog :

```
$(function() {  
    $( "#newarticle-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 700,
        modal: true,
        resizable:false,
        buttons: {
                "Ajouter article": function() {
                        .... here is the preparation of the submit ....

            $("#newarticleform").submit();
                 $(this).dialog("close");
            },

               "Fermer": function() {
                   $(this).dialog( "close" );
               }
            }
    });

 $("#New") //The button to open the dialog
    .click(function() {
        $("#newarticle-form").dialog("open");

    });
});
```

It works well !

This page have a second jquery ui dialog. When I add it with the same method (but not the same ids), this dialog opens and closes about one second later.

Why ?

Comment: Could you post this into a JS fiddle? Would help a lot... :)

Comment: I don't know how. I'll try to do it now. Wait a while...

Comment: I don't know how to implement jqueru-ui in JSFiddle... :-/

Comment: on the left, under 'Manage Resources' add the following url: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Thak you for your help !!  It works in JSFiddle ! o_O (There are some other bugs because all the details are not develooped now (error message are remaining between calls, for example))